# Devise invalid forgot password URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have model User. And models

CaBase < User
LaUser < User

Both models has:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
     :trackable, :validatable
```

LaUser- Users that have access to Admin area.
CaBase - Users that has access only for front-end.

When I click on forgot password on CaBase login form, it mails me with link like:

```
site_name/admin/password/edit?reset_password_token=gtwSWQK8HH2-6p4CHp
```

But I need it to

```
site_name/password/edit?reset_password_token=gtwSWQK8HH2-6p4CHp
```

Also I have actions in ApplicationController

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(LaUser)
      admin_root_path
    else
      dashboard_index_path
    end
  end

  def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(LaUser)
      admin_root_path
    else
      dashboard_index_path
    end
  end
```

What can I do with it?

UPD1:

```
get 'dashboard/index'

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :la_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  devise_for :ca_base, path: '', path_names: {sign_in: 'login'}
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'welcome#index'

  resource :ca_administrators, only: [:new, :create]
```

Comment: show `routes.rb` please.

Comment: @Зелёный update question

Comment: i can't answer on this question, but you can `rails generate devise:views`(this generate devise mailer views too) and past link that you need.

Comment: Спасибо большое) Обязательно попробую)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in that I don't checked which role have current user.

Code from Devise Mailer.

```
 if record.is_a?(LaUser)
      controller = 'active_admin/devise/passwords'
    else
      controller = 'devise/passwords'
    end

    edit_password_url = url_for(
        controller: controller,
        action: :edit,
        reset_password_token: token
    )
```